# Pre-process audio data (fft spectrum, peak, etc.) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I can currently play an audio track using the JavaScript Web Audio API. While this track is playing I can extract the FFT spectrum data, the peak value, the RMS value, etc.

However, for the purposes of my application, I need to be able to extract all of this data from the track before I begin playing it.

Is there any way to do this using the Web Audio API. If not, how else might this be done?

I tried to achieve this by using the following code but it returned the exact same values for each 'frame':

Loading the audio when the user chooses a file:

```
var fileChooser = document.getElementById("chooseAudio");
var audio = null;

var file = fileChooser.files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    audio = new Audio(reader.result);
}

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Once the audio has been loaded:

```
var FPS = 60;
var INCREMENT = 1 / FPS;
var FFT_SIZE = 256;
var SMOOTHING = 0.7;

var duration = null;
var length = null;
var width = null;
var time = null;

var analyser = null;
var data = null;
var index = null;

function analyse() {

    duration = audio.duration / APR;
    length = Math.ceil(duration * FPS);
    width = 4;
    time = 0.0;

    data = array(length, width);
    index = 0;

    var context = new AudioContext();

    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = FFT_SIZE;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = SMOOTHING;

    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    audio.play();

    while (index < length) {

        audio.currentTime = time;

        frame = getFrame();
        data[index] = frame;

        time += INCREMENT;
        index++;

    }

    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;

}

function getFrame() {

    var rawFreq = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(rawFreq);

    var rawTimeDom = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(rawTimeDom);

    var frame = [];
    frame.push(peak(rawTimeDom), rms(rawTimeDom), low(rawFreq), high(rawFreq));

    return frame;

}
```

Output of `data`:

```
[
  [128, 128, 100.2, 68.3],
  [128, 128, 100.2, 68.3],
  ...
  [128, 128, 100.2, 68.3]
]
```

Also, I should clarify that the reason I am attempting to sample the audio 60 times-per-second is because I will need to display the audio data later at that same rate.

Comment: So the purpose is to do mostly visuals, as I undersood, right?

Comment: @Conor  Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `OfflineAudioContext` instead of an `AudioContext` to preprocess the data instead of running the audio pipeline in real time.

[From the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext):

> An OfflineAudioContext doesn't render the audio to the device hardware; instead, it generates it, as fast as it can, and outputs the result to an AudioBuffer.

You can do your processing in an offline context before using the normal context to play the audio!

Answer (score 0):

If you really do have a set of files and need to process them up front, use [`decodeAudioData`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-baseaudiocontext-decodeaudiodata) to get the audio data from each file.  Use an `OfflineAudioContext` instead of an `AudioContext` to get the analyser data.  However, since the offline context can run faster than real time, you'll need to be careful on when you call `getByteTimeDomainData`.  It's probably best to use [`suspend`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-offlineaudiocontext-suspend) and [`resume`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-baseaudiocontext-resume) here, where you call `getFrame` in `suspend`.

However, based on what `getFrame` does (getting audio samples), you might be better off using a [`ScriptProcessorNode`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#scriptprocessornode) or [`AudioWorklet`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioworklet) to get the time-domain data that you're looking for.  These work for an `AudioContext` or `OfflineAudioContext`.